# What is a Twilio REST client?

Tags: twilio

I've basically just gotten started with Salesforce (forgive me if the questions are super basic), and am trying to figure out how to integrate Twilio into it - in the Quick Start instructions it says "Create a Twilio REST client to get started."

Can someone help explain what exactly that means or point me to a resource (or a few resources) that breaks it down into language that someone who is just starting can understand?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [github repo](https://github.com/britishboyindc/TextToCase_Twilio_Salesforce) that can take a text from Twilio and creates a case with it - and lets a user send a text back through Twilio via a VF page...

The repo contains the REST client you are referring to - basically, a way for SF to talk to Twilio via Twilio's REST API - and you can receive a text back by using the Twilio ability to post to a REST endpoint that gets setup in SF

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it means to create an account over at https://www.twilio.com/ and use the account to create a REST client in the twilio admin.